# Finding a point that is $\theta$ degrees and $r$ distance away from the given point

Tags: geometry

[Here is the image for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBMiM.png)

Given the values for $(x, y)$, $(a, b)$, $r$, and $\theta$, the task is to find the coordinates $(u, v)$.

I'm currently programming a game, however, been stuck on this problem for a while. I need to find points on the 2D plane that is at most $r$ distance away, and $\theta$ degrees away from my point located at $(a, b)$. This point can be located anywhere (a fixed distance from the circle, but on any side of it). This is what I've come up with so far:

I subtract the position of the center of circle $(x, y)$ from $(a, b)$, and this gives me a vector, which I normalize and scale up by multiplying by $r$ (I know the resulting distance of $(u, v)$ from $(x, y)$ won't be exactly $r$ in this case, but it doesn't matter to be precise here, since it's just a game). This resulting vector can be expressed simply as some coordinates $(x1 - x, y1 - y)$, where $(x1, y1)$ are the coordinates of the endpoint of the vector. So then I add $(x, y)$ to this vector to get the endpoint's coordinates. Then I divide this by $cos($$\theta$$)$, but the result isn't what I expect. Any help on what I'm doing wrong on the last stage?

Comment: It seems like you’re just guessing here. Why would you divide by $\cos\theta$?! Do you know how to generate a vector that makes an angle of $\theta$ with the positive $x$-axis?

Answer (score 1):

Trigonometry will allow to show that: ( I am assuming that, in the picture you attached $\phi = \theta$ in your problem statement)

$$ (l +l_p)^2 + l_n^2 = l_h^2 $$

where, $l = \sqrt{(a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2}$ ; $l_h = \sqrt{(u-x)^2 + (v-y)^2}$ ; $l_n = r\sin{\theta}$ and $l_p = r\cos{\theta}$

Using we will get:

$$ u^2 + v^2 - 2ux -2vy = \alpha$$
with, $\alpha = 2 r \sqrt{(a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2} \cos{\theta} +r^2+a^2+b^2 -2ax -2by$

The constraint of your problem gives the another equation,

$$ u^2 + v^2 - 2ua -2vb = \beta$$
with, $\beta = r^2-a^2-b^2$

Both, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known since you are giving them as input. A simplification using the two above equation is:

$$ u(a-x)+v(b-y) = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha - \beta)$$

It's not easy to isolate $u$ and $v$. Any step possible further will be appreciated.